# Architecture Incompatibility with Brother Printer Drivers in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: drivers, printing, 21.04, brother, arm64

The printer is a Brother MFC-J430W, and the OS is Ubuntu 21.04. The conection is by USB cable. When at the beggining I plugged the printer to the computer, aparently it recognized it and installed the drivers, but when I tried to print nothings happened. Although it indicated "printing completed".

Then I went to brother support and download the drivers for this model. They didn't have expecificallly one for ubuntu system, so I donwloaded the ones for linux debian.

During the instalation process of the drivers package by CLI this is the output:

```
dpkg -i --force-all mfcj430wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package architecture (i386) does not match system (arm64)
(Reading database ... 186773 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mfcj430wlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb ...
Unpacking mfcj430wlpr:i386 (3.0.1-1) over (3.0.1-1) ...
Setting up mfcj430wlpr:i386 (3.0.1-1) ...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/spool/lpd/mfcj430w’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot access '/var/spool/lpd/mfcj430w': No such file or directory
chgrp: cannot access '/var/spool/lpd/mfcj430w': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/var/spool/lpd/mfcj430w': No such file or directory

dpkg -i --force-all mfcj430wcupswrapper-3.0.0-1a.i386.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package architecture (i386) does not match system (arm64)
Selecting previously unselected package mfcj430wcupswrapper:i386.
(Reading database ... 186773 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mfcj430wcupswrapper-3.0.0-1a.i386.deb ...
Unpacking mfcj430wcupswrapper:i386 (3.0.0-1) ...
Setting up mfcj430wcupswrapper:i386 (3.0.0-1) ...
Restarting cups (via systemctl): cups.service.
lpadmin -p MFCJ430W -E -v usb://dev/usb/lp0 -P /usr/share/cups/model/Brother/brother_mfcj430w_printer_en.ppd
lpadmin: Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS.
#

Will you specify the Device URI? [Y/n] ->n

Test Print? [y/N] ->N

You are going to install following packages.
   brscan4-0.4.10-1.i386.deb
dpkg -i --force-all brscan4-0.4.10-1.i386.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package architecture (i386) does not match system (arm64)
(Reading database ... 186777 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack brscan4-0.4.10-1.i386.deb ...
Unpacking brscan4:i386 (0.4.10-1) over (0.4.10-1) ...
Setting up brscan4:i386 (0.4.10-1) ...
This software is based in part on the work of the Independent JPEG Group.

You are going to install following packages.
   brscan-skey-0.3.1-2.i386.deb
dpkg -i --force-all brscan-skey-0.3.1-2.i386.deb
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: package architecture (i386) does not match system (arm64)
Selecting previously unselected package brscan-skey:i386.
(Reading database ... 186777 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack brscan-skey-0.3.1-2.i386.deb ...
Unpacking brscan-skey:i386 (0.3.1-2) ...
dpkg: brscan-skey:i386: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 brscan-skey:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.3.4-1).
 brscan-skey:i386 depends on libsane (>= 1.0.11-3).

Setting up brscan-skey:i386 (0.3.1-2) ...
apt-get install libusb-0.1-4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 brscan-skey:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.4-1) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.11-3) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Looking at the warnings messages above, many warn that drivers doesn't match with the architecture of the system. However there aren't any other drivers available, or at least I don't know them.

When I tried to print after this driver installation, as expected, nothing happened, now without any message of "printing completed".

Have anybody any solution? It is posible to solve this architecture incompatibility? Any response will be apreciated. Many Thanks

Comment: Do you have ARM system? I would not install i386 driver. My Brother works but it installed 3 printers and only one works or works well. Does your model have Wi-Fi?

Comment: Apparently the manufacturer (Brother) provides drivers for "normal" PC architecture only, not for your ARM architecture. If you don't find alternative drivers that are (or can be) compiled for ARM, then you might not be able to use the printer/scanner. You could try the "CUPSwrapper Printer driver Source Codes" package provided by brother. (I don't know if this is a complete printer driver or if it requires some other closed-source driver.)

Comment: This might help. Though, you should not need the package from brother and indeed it might not run on arm. https://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/install-and-configure-linux-driver-for-brother-mfc-j430w/ is your computer a raspberry pi?

Comment: The "arch" command reports the name of the hardware that you have.  It is also visible when you run  "uname -a".

Comment: @Bruni I read the documentation provided by your link. And tried to connect my printer by wifi, using CUPS but still didn't work. It's very anoying when it says printing completed, and nothing happens ;( And yes my computer is a raspberry pi 4 Thanks for you comment anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go to

https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan (mainpage)

Then to

https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/

You install **ipp-usb**

You report whether whether you have success.

(Purge ippusbxd beforehand).

I should read properly! The above instructions are for amd64 on Ubuntu 20.04. All that Daniel has to do for printing is to check whether ipp-usb is already installed (it should be) from the arm64 archive : `apt install ipp-usb`

Plug the printer in. Check that the ipp-usb service is active with `systemctl status ipp-usb.service`. **Driverless printing** should be immediately available to you. (If it is not, I have another technique to make it so).

**SUMMARY**

Unfortunately, the MFC-J430W is too old to take advantage of ipp-usb on any architecture. Brother does not provide drivers for arm64 either. AFAICT, your only chance of getting it working is to use wireless and read [this.](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSQuickPrintQueues)

It is possible the MFC-J430W might require a firmware update to get an AirPrint service. There is one from 2013 [here.](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj430w_all&os=10013) The IPP-over-USB protocol was ratified in 2012 so, who knows, ipp-usb might work too. [This user's post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250945231) was useful.

Comment: Thanks @brian_p for your response. Hovewer this link you added is for solving problems relating to scanning. Also my printer model isn't in their list. Do you have the same printer model? Solve this problem with this solution?

Comment: @Daniel Batería The instruction to install ipp-usb passed you by? You were given the link to it.

Comment: Hi @brian_p I tried your solution and this happened:                                               
~$ sudo apt purge uppusbxd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package uppusbxd

$ sudo dpkg -i ipp-usb_0.9.19-1+50.1_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive ipp-usb_0.9.19-1+50.1_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ipp-usb_0.9.19-1+50.1_amd64.deb

Comment: Hi @Daniel Batería I have amended my answer.

Comment: Hi @brian_p don't worry about the previous mistake, on the contrary many thanks for your time ;) I tryed your alternative solution: I checked that I had ipp-usb already installed. After that I plugged the printer, I typed: `systemctl status ipp-usb.service` and this was the response:
`● ipp-usb.service - Daemon for IPP over USB printer support
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ipp-usb.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:ipp-usb(8)`
It seems it keeps inactive, although I plugged the printer. Any idea to solve it?...

Comment: @Daniel Batería I have added to my answer. Let's hope https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201311 is correct.

Comment: Hi @briand_p thanks for your support, it seems this printer is not gonna work with my raspi 4. We let it go. I will apreciate your help, so I will mark and accept your answer. I will see if I can update the firmware of the printer, so it could suppors airprint. If so I almost will be able to print through my iphone. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Batería Thank you for engaging with the issue. There is yet another addition to my answer. I think you could be in luck! Apple has the device down as an AirPrint device. Brother must have submitted that info and would surely know its capabilities.